# sudo apt-get update not working and ctrl+alt+t not working

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, python

I am using ubuntu 18.04
I have installed python 3.6  and 3.7 together and set default 3.7
Now I am facing two problems:

1. when I am trying to

   `sudo apt-get update`
   it shows the error

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
   from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator

   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>

   import apt_pkg

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

   Error in sys.excepthook:

   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook

   from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes

   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>

   from apport.report import Report

   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>

   import apport.fileutils

   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>

   from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging

   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>

    import apt

    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>

    import apt_pkg

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
   ```
2. `ctrl+alt+t` command does not open gnome terminal

**My Questions are :**

1. Is there any solution to recover?

   **OR**
2. How can I reset ubuntu default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's try to "help" with the second topic, but it should work to open the keyboard shortcut settings and setup a new shortcut CTRL+ALT+T for the executable gnome-terminal this doesn't fix the issue why it's not working anymore as it used to do, but at least it's recovering functionality.

To the first question:
What is the current output of:

```
which python3
```

Do a

```
ls -alFh
```

On the result. What's it linking to?
Can you try to reset the link /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/bin/python3.6 with

```
su
# enter root passwd. 
cd /usr/bin
unlink python3
ln -s python3.6 python3
```

*please check before if /usr/bin/python3.6 exists.*

Does apt work again?

Comment: I have already tried from keyboard shortcut but not work any way. when I type ```which python3``` it gives  ```usr/bin/python3```

Comment: when I type ``` ls -alFh``` it shows  ```pip3.7 -> /home/username/.local/bin/pip3.7*
```  I have flowed a tutorial to set python3.7 as default and lost the link so I can't not reset  @JacknJo

Comment: What does `ll /usr/bin/python3` give?

Comment: It works perfectly . Thanks a lots @JacknJo

Comment: I have just used your following code ```cd /usr/bin
unlink python3
ln -s python3.6 python3```

Comment: I think upgrading python to a newer version should be done by the distribution maintainers. If you want to use python 3.7, use #!/usr/bin/python3.7 as a shebang in your scripts.